# Gridview's update event firing even though data is invalid in controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an commandfield and few templatefields. The templatefields have validators attached to it and they show up proper messages  when wrong data is selected. However when I click commandfield no error is shown and the event fires even though data is invalid. Morover, I have also checked Page.IsValid on server and all works out well even though data is in invalid state. This the markup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Exp. Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblExpiration" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Expiration")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate  >
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMM" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">MM</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" >01</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">02</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">03</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4">04</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="5">05</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6">06</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="7">07</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="8">08</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="9">09</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <span class="green"></span> /&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYY" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <span class="green"></span>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvddlMM" ControlToValidate="ddlMM" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="-1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvddlYY" ControlToValidate="ddlYY" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="-1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:CommandField 
 UpdateText="Update" CausesValidation="true"
    HeaderText="Update" ShowEditButton="true" 
    EditText="Update <br/>Exp. Date" ButtonType="Link" />
```

Please do not pay attention to the weird control names and styles. Basically the template field has dropdownlists of year and month. Year's drop down list is populated in rowdatabound event. As you can see validators are attached still commandfield works normally. Can anybody tell me what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I would say you do not have `ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid"` on `asp:CommandField`. Change your commandfield to:

```
<asp:CommandField ValidationGroup="vgExpDateGrid"
 UpdateText="Update" CausesValidation="true"
  HeaderText="Update" ShowEditButton="true" 
  EditText="Update <br/>Exp. Date" ButtonType="Link" />
```

or alternatively remove `ValidationGroup` from `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`